# nrwl - ng generate gives maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl

getting Maximum call stack size exceeded

`ng generate @nrwl/schematics:library feature-restaurant-profile --parentModule=apps/web-kmeal-restaurant/src/app/app.module.ts --routing --lazy --dry-run --no-interactive`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug this without looking at the layout of your workspace. Can you include the relevant parts of your `package.json` (for versions of schematics, angular nad nx) `nx.json` (for project config of feature-restaurant-profile and web-kmeal-restaurant) and `angular.json` (for same configs)?